# Is there a better way of bulk selections in sql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, database

Assuming i have a database table 'UserInformation' with thousands of entries.

| id | user_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | value_1 |
| 2 | 1 | B | value_2 |
| 3 | 2 | A | value_3 |
| 4 | 2 | B | value_4 |
| 5 | 2 | C | value_5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For simplicity, my task is to select all entries with a specific user_id and type A or B and assign the values to an UserModel Object (in Java).
But i have to select those information for thousands of user ids (e.g. user = 10.000 entries).

I know two ways of achieving this:

1.

```java
public List<UserModel> getUsers(List<User> users){
    List<UserModel> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : users){
        String valueA = findValueByUserIdAndType(user.getId(), "A");
        String valueB = findValueByUserIdAndType(user.getId(), "B");
        userModels.add(new UserModel(user.getId(), valueA, valueB);
    }
    return userModels;
}
```

2. 

```java
public List<UserModel> getUsers(List<User> users){
    List<UserModel> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
    List<UserInformation> entries = findAllByUserIdInAndTypeIn(userIds, List.of("A", "B");
    Map<Long, List<UserInformation>> entriesMappedByUserId = groupByUserId(entries);
    
    for (User user : users){
      UserInformation userInformation = entriesMappedByUserId.get(user.getId());
      userModels.add(new UserModel(user.getId(), userInformation);
    }

    return userModels;
}
```

I know the first method yields in 20.000 database queries. But the second one leads me to two questions:

- Is there a better way than transforming the database result into a map and retrieving the values based on an identifier
- Assuming the second database query uses an in clause in the sql query (where user_id in (1,2,3,...,10000), at which number do i break my database

And the resulting question: Is there a better way to select a huge number of entries?

**Edit:** Assume the User table and UserInformation table can't be joined because the information is stored on two different places.

Comment: "...at which number do i break my database..." -- That depends on a specific database, and the specific version of it. As a general rule engines typìcally accept hundreds but you would reach some limits at 1000 (oracle, for example). I would try with increasing sets of values to check your specific engine/version and also the specific JDBC driver limitations.

Comment: Al alternative way (that I have seen sometimes implemented) is to create a temp table, batch-insert all parameters on it and then a simple join would get all the info you need in a single query.

Comment: I would go for selecting UserInformation joinned with user table. You should get same amount of rows but "username" for example will be fetched as many times as there are rows of UserInformation. Then create Set<UserModel> and in row mapper just add rows to the Set if there is user from row in set. If there is user in set just add row information into it. Ideally UserModel should have hashcode and equals based on id of user.

Comment: Generally everything depends on performance, sometimes 10000selects is faster than one big. But it's not a rule. Maybe it would be better for you to just do select * from user and select * from userinformation and just merge them in java. It depends on size of database and your ram size :D

Comment: Ok, i forgot to mention. User table and UserInformation table can't be joined. Assume they are on different databases. My core question rather relates to the problem of querying thousands of requests or 1 request and merging them to the right object (which has the problems of the 'in' clause)